# View an instance as XML?

Tags: alloy

The instances generated by the Alloy Analyzer can be viewed as text -- simply click on the Txt icon on the menu bar at the top of the tool. The text is a long, unformatted string. Is it possible to format the text as XML? Perhaps someone has written an XSLT program to convert the raw text to XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any obtained instances can be exported to XML.

```
File > Export To > XML ... in the instance viewer.
```

Comment: Wow! All this time and I wasn't aware of this. I will definitely use this capability. Thank you (again) @Loïc Gammaitoni

Comment: My pleasure as always ;)